# Use process.env variable in typeorm.forroot

Tags: typeorm, nestjs

Following this guide: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/sql

When I try to use process.env.DB_PASS in connection options, no password is passed into mysql. When I pass a raw string, it works. Dotenv config was done prior to nest app module creation.

What would be the best way to do this correctly?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      username: 'root',
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: 'dbname',
      entities: ['./models/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  components: []
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {...}
```

Comment: We are using env variables in our call to `forRoot` and it works. I assume your module file (the typescript file containing this code) is imported (`import`) **before** dotenv does the work.  `dotenv` should be the very first thing imported/done by your app, except if you have very good reasons to do something else.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I was thinking about the order of operations incorrectly. It seems the metadata resolution occurs prior to the NestFactory.create(AppModule), so I moved dotenv.config() to above the app module import instead of before the NestFactory.create(AppModule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using env variables in our call to `forRoot` and it works. I assume your module file (the typescript file containing this code) is imported (`import`) **before** dotenv does the work.  `dotenv` should be the very first thing imported/done by your app, except if you have very good reasons to do something else.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what you mean by "before dotenv does the work"/"dotenv should be the very first thing imported/done by your app"?

Comment: According to OP's post, I assume that he/she is using `dotenv` to fill `process.env` variables. What I explained is that `dotenv.load()` must be executed before any `import` involving an access to `process.env` is processed.

TL;DR: `dotenv.load()`  must have been executed before any `process.env.` value is read.

Comment: Hi @VinceOPS, thanks for getting back. I didn't realize that we have to explicitly do a `dotenv.load()`. I was thinking NestJS automagically makes the .env variables available in the classes. (I am very new to NodeJS/JS world). Thanks for the answer!